# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csv' in miniconda environment

Tags: python, csv, anaconda, miniconda

I need help, i'm new to programming, i tried to run jupyter notebook from my laptop and i got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csv' in the miniconda environment. I've tried to find a solution to this and can't work my way around this issue. I need help in fixing this error so i can be able to load jupyter notebook.

```
(C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Personal_projects\aws_machine_learning\env) C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Personal_projects\aws_machine_learning>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Personal_projects\aws_machine_learning\env\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Personal_projects\aws_machine_learning\env\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 62, in <module>
from tornado import web
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Personal_projects\aws_machine_learning\env\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 90, in <module>
import tornado.locale
File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Personal_projects\aws_machine_learning\env\lib\site-packages\tornado\locale.py", line 41, in <module>
import csv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'csv'
```

Comment: Weird... `csv` is a built-in module - it's supposed to be preinstalled on any Python installation

Comment: I had an issue a while back and part of the solution was to delete csv.py or csv.pyc file and i did that, i think that is what is affecting my jupyter notebook. I have uninstalled and reinstalled miniconda and i'm still having the same issue

Comment: You should probably reinstall Python itself

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled python and i'm still having the same issue

Comment: Since you're using a virtual environment, maybe the standard library is copied into `aws_machine_learning\env`? (Not sure about that) So, maybe the CSV module should be present _in the virtual environment_? If so, you could recreate the virtual environment or just copy the CSV module from the standard library

Comment: I removed the conda environment from the directory i wanted to activate using `conda env remove --name myenv`, created a new folder and a new conda environment in it and it worked, my jupyter notebook is working